# legal question about facebook authorization

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, authorization

I am having problems with the facebook authorization process within my app.
I want to post something on the users facebook page with a dialog which is shown to the user first, and request the "publish_stream" permission.
If I do so the user is redirected every 2 hours to the request page where it says that the user has already allowed this app to do this, which is very annoying for the user....

So my question is what happens if I don't ask about permission to post on the wall, but still show the user the dialog which shows what is posted on his page? is this legal ? can I get any problems what so ever by doing this?
Cause posting on the users wall without asking permission, works just fine.

thanks for the help

Comment: You could just ask for 'offline_access' permission as well as the post - this should stop the constant signing in requirement.

Comment: @deanWombourne I already read that, but this sounds super scary to the user and I don't want to give the user the impression my app posts on his wall without him knowing. thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook documentation states that if you prompt for publish_stream, you will be able to post on the users wall indefinitely, and thus you wouldn't also need offline_access.

> publish_stream    Enables your app to
>   post content, comments, and likes to a
>   user's stream and to the streams of
>   the user's friends. **With this
>   permission, you can publish content to
>   a user's feed at any time, without
>   requiring offline_access.** However,
>   please note that Facebook recommends a
>   user-initiated sharing model.

Comment: unfortunatelly this is not quite true.... if I request publish_stream I only get a token valid for 2 hours. if I check for `isSessionValid` after this 2 hours it will redirect me to the permission page. ;(

Comment: isSessionValid may fail because you wont be able to get basic info, etc but you can still post with that token.

Comment: but how do I decide then when to show the permission page if `isSessionValid`fails? and I am pretty sure I can even post on the wall without a token.

Comment: I also am still trying to figure out how to validate you can still publish to their wall as them.  Only way I can think of is to try to publish first and if it fails prompt them.

Comment: this sounds perfect. there is the methode 'dialog:didFailWithError:' but this gets also called when there is no internet connection,.... so how do I know when to prompt permission screen? is there a list off erros somewhere ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no legal issues there. However users will be pi**ed off.
But when you request a token with offline_access and then use that token for publish_stream, your token will not expire.

Comment: @Kumar thanks for your answer. But if i use the offline_access the user will get prompted the following message "Access my data any time: APP_NAME may access my data when I'm not using the application." this sounds very scary for the user I think! At least this would scare me away and I wouldn't allow this application to do so! So don't I scare user away from user the fb integration ?

Comment: Yes, do a flurry analytics and see how many users cancel out of FBlogin (Do a bean counting on number of clicks on login button vs number of times the fbDidNotLogin delegate was called. Make a decision based on that. I don't think many users will back off reading that atleast compared to flooding a user's wall

Comment: @Kumar very good idea. I have flurry already implemented so that is a very easy way.